# How to 'narrow' onchange for specific id?

Tags: jquery, binding, jquery-selectors

I found this cod on [jquery web](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

```
$("select").change(function () {
      var str = "";
      $("select option:selected").each(function () {
            str += $(this).text() + " ";
          });
      $("div").text(str);
    })
    .change();
```

I can use it for I want but I want this function to be fired only for `#my_id`. I tried to insert `#my_id` after both selects but then the function does nothing.

I though I could bind this function to only select with specific id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That works fine for `select#my_id`:

> http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/wAU5w/

Did you use `select #my_id` (note the space) my mistake?

The `select#my_id` selector matches the `<select id="my_id">` element, the `select #my_id` matches anything with and `id="my_id"` that is a child of a `<select>`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Works nice now.

Comment: One more question. Why is the `.change();` in the code? At the very end?

Comment: @Radek: Probably to initialize the `<div>` to match the initial selections in the `<select>`. Try my fiddle without it and see what happens.

Answer (score 1):

as in?

```
$("#my_id").change(function () {
  var str = "";
  $("#my_id :selected").each(function () {
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
      });
  $("div").text(str);
})
.change();
```

Answer (score 1):

This will only work for < select > elements. You shouldn't need it but try this:

```
$("select#my_id").change...
```

also make sure it's wrapped in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

To make sure the DOM is ready

Answer (score 1):

If your `select` is labeled `my_id` than just swap

`select`

for

`#my_id`

in the two places where it occurs in the script.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this:

```
$("select#my_id").change(function() {
    var selOpts = jQuery.map($(":selected", $(this)), function(opt, index) {
        return $(opt).text();
    });
    $("div").text(selOpts.join(" "));
}).change();
```